# Inheritance - Models.py from a installed GitHub-App

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-scheduler

I've integrated [Django-Scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler) into my project that has a [events.py](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler/blob/develop/schedule/models/events.py) file that creates a "title" in the class "Event". I've added some other variables with Inheritance.For the next Step I need to change Title into a ForeignKey, thats why I've tried this little code:

```
from django.db import models
from schedule.models import Event

class LessonEvent(Event):

    title = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Because of the Fact that the original class Event has not `Abstract=True` in the Meta Django gives me this Error:

> ```
> lessons.LessonEvent.title: (models.E006) The field 'title' clashes with the field 'title' from model 'schedule.event'
> ```

Is there a way to solve this, without touching the code of the django-scheduler app?

Comment: Why don't you just change the name of your field to something else? `title_field` perhaps? you aren't touching the Scheduler class don't worry, inheritance is downwards not upwards.

Comment: Shure that will work, but afterwards the calendar shows "title" in the calendarView and I want that this calendar is showing my Foreign Key. It would also be always a required to fill something in the title at the admin section.